# Scroll down wheel too mouse 5 function

Tags: windows, mouse

Is it possible to modify scroll down wheel so that it performs mouse 5 function. For example; each time you hear the click of the wheel as you scroll down it will repeat mouse 5 function.. so in a way im swapping scroll down with mouse 5 function

Comment: What kind of mouse? What kind of computer? What Operating System (and version)? What is "mouse 5 function"? Each mouse has its own software and anything that it offers special is likely to have its own API. This question right now is both unclear and way too broad; it is likely to be closed on that basis.

Comment: g400 Logitech mouse/ mouse 5button on the side of mouse/ windows 10

Answer (score 0):

The software download of
[Logitech Options](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025297893)
may do what you are looking for.

It is described as:

> Logitech Options is a powerful and easy-to-use application that enhances your Logitech mice, keyboards, and touchpads. Customize your device with Options and do more than you thought possible.

If Logitech Options cannot do the job,
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
can most probably be programmed to do that (with some work on your side).